# Suggested R packages for frontier estimation or segmentation of hyperspectral images

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, image-processing

An **hyperspectral image is** a multidimensional image with more than 200 spectral bands i.e. an image for which each pixel is a vector of dimension 200 (most often it is a sampled spectral curve that is encoutered in satellite imagery or medical imagery).

What are the **implemented package** (I am especially interested in R packages but if other free algorithms exist, I will try them) for **frontier detection** and (unsupervised) **segmentation** of this type of images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid there is no; during my little adventure with such data we have just converted it to a data frame form, added some extra attributes made from neighborhoods of pixels and used standard methods. Still, packages [ripa](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ripa/index.html) and [hyperSpec](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hyperSpec/index.html) might be useful.
For other software, I've got an impression that most of sensible applications are commercial.

Answer (score 4):

Not an R package, but D. A. Landgrebe from Purdue (author of *Signal theory methods in multispectral remote sensing*) has sponsored the [MultiSpec](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~biehl/MultiSpec/) freeware.  Its a rather clunky GUI but gets the job done for most of the common hyperspectral algorithms.

Comment: interesting ! there are testing images to try it, exercices to learn how to use it...

Answer (score 3):

The best place to look for free/open source capabilities of this nature is GRASS GIS.  The image processing manual is [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/imagery/grass4_image_processing.pdf).  Because this is constantly undergoing development, it would be worthwhile posting an inquiry on one of the GRASS user lists (found through links on the home page [here](https://grass.osgeo.org).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I'll do the inquiry when I'll have more time

Comment: We have also a dedicated Wiki page at http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late response, so this may no longer be of interest, but I am working on putting together an R library with various hyperspectral image processing capabilities. At the moment my focus has been on endmember detection and unmixing. If this is still something which is of interest please let me know. My hope is to publish a beta version to CRAN or R-Forge in the near future but I would be happy to send out the code itself.

Best,
Dan

Comment: Hi Dan, Good initiative, I'll try to contact you.

Comment: Has anything come of this/will come of this? I'm much interested...